# Vertx not able to resolve host and not able to download large file using webclient

Tags: webclient, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am trying to download file from server but getting an error

Checked some solution where i found need to disable the dnsresolver but that also don't work for me.

Here is the code to disable dnsresolver

```
System.setProperty("vertx.disableDnsResolver", "true");
```

Source code :-

```
WebClientOptions webClientOptions = new WebClientOptions() .setSsl(true)
                .setTrustAll(true)
                .setDefaultPort(443)
                .setKeepAlive(true);
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx,webClientOptions);
        final HttpRequest<Buffer> abs = webClient.get("https://downloads.dell.com","/xyz.exe");
        abs.send(responseHandler ->{
            if (responseHandler.succeeded()){
                String temp = vertx.fileSystem().createTempFileBlocking("", "");
                            vertx.fileSystem().writeFileBlocking(temp, responseHandler.result().body());
                        routingContext.response().end("Success");

            }else{
                log.error("Error: {}",responseHandler.cause());
                routingContext.response().end("failure");
            }
        });
```

Here is an Exception:-

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'https://downloads.dell.com'. Exceeded max queries per resolve 4 
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:927) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:886) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:358) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:858) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:358) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:858) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:358) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:858) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:358) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:1001) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:878) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:358) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:545) [netty-resolver-dns-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
```

Update :-
Using getAbs() I am able to download file around 15 to 20 mb, but In case of file size more than 500mb Not able to download

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebClient.get(String, String)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClient.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method expects a host name and a path, but you provide a URL as first parameter.

If you want to use a URL, use the [`WebClient.getAbs(String)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/WebClient.html#getAbs-java.lang.String-) method:

```
final HttpRequest<Buffer> abs = webClient.getAbs("https://downloads.dell.com/xyz.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks @tsegismont, May I know the reason why I am not able to download file more than 500MB, is there any way to download file more than 500MB over webclient

Answer (score 0):

Its resolving for me just fine

```
fun main() {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  val webClientOptions = WebClientOptions().setSsl(true)
    .setTrustAll(true)
    .setDefaultPort(443)
    .setKeepAlive(true)

  val webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, webClientOptions)
  val abs = webClient.getAbs("https://downloads.dell.com/xyz.exe")
  abs.send().onComplete { println(it.failed()) }.onSuccess { println(it.statusMessage()) }
}

// prints
// false
// Not Found
```

Comment: Is that any issue with get call, I am still getting same error